# how to build clusters that are approximately balanced in size in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-computing

As seen above,how to build clusters that are approximately balanced in size in sklearn?I have a question，clustering is done according to certain rules,Why can we specify the number in cluster?Anyway, I want to know how to achieve this step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some methods (for example, non-sklearn's HDBSCAN: https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter_selection.html) have parameters like minimal_cluster_size. Probably, sklearn's DBSCAN's min_samples will work the similar way. It will not give you exact 'balanced' clusters but may help.

But in my opinion, sometimes it is more reasonable to run clusterization algorithms with different parameters and select 'more balanced' output by your hands. In this case you can see what points are not separable and probably add more data (calculate additional distance matrix, for example) or change target metric.

> Why can we specify the number in cluster?

Because the tasks 'find clusters' and 'balance them' are a bit opposite in their meaning in the most cases. I'm not even speaking about algorithms when you need to specify the number of clusters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I think you are very professional.I think you have solved some problems.I see someone writing a lot of such programs about "same size cluster".But I could not find it in sklearn.You give me inspiration.Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I have another idea about it.Calculate the number of each label, then calculate the variance,and get the one with the smallest variance